# How Can I Create a List in Discord.js Using MongoDB Database?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, list, discord, discord.js

```
{"_id":
{"$oid":"5f97bbea986057000494e4cf"},
"ban":{"onoff":"on","lmite":{"$numberInt":"3"}},
"kick":{"onoff":"on",
"lmite":{"$numberInt":"3"}},
"channel":{"onoff":"on",
"lmite":{"$numberInt":"3"}},
"role":{"onoff":"on",
"lmite":{"$numberInt":"3"}},
"spam":{"onoff":"on"},
"bot":{"onoff":"on"},
"prefix":"p!",
"punishment":"ban",
"whitelist":[{"type":"735874386200100974"},
{"type":"737611247989686333"},
{"type":"565962204327968769"}],
"time":{"$numberInt":"60"},
"guildID":"754345876352401571",
"__v":{"$numberInt":"0"}}
```

I have this database array and I want to create a whitelist, however, I do not know how I can create it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: It looks like you already have a whitelist array?